# What does return object means in Java

Tags: java, object, return

I know that java is return by value not by reference, so it makes a copy of the object and passes the new copy. Is this is the case with the return statements also?
Does the

```
return obj;
```

creates a new object copy or simply returns the current object itself.

Comment: You say "_I know that java is return by value not by reference, so it makes a copy of the object and passes the new copy_". That is nothing but incorrect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Comment: @jlordo: Yes, you are right.
Can I say "it makes a copy of the reference to the object and not the object itself"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is a wrong assumption. It's true that **Java passes everything by value**, but this means the following:

- Scalar variables contain values, so you can easily see that they are passed by value.
- Object variables, on the other hand, *do not contain objects*. You could think of them as containing a pseudo-address to an object. That pseudo-address is copied (by value), *but it still points to the same object*. (Objects are actually created only using a `new` expression.)

The above is true (for both types of variables) for assignments, arguments and return values.

Answer (score 2):

`so it makes a copy of the object and passes the new copy`

No! it does not!

Return by value means the the value in the `obj` reference is returned, if `obj` points to some object,other reference which collects a return value from this returning method will also point to the same object as which `obj` is pointing to.

No, it does not create another object to return.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't copy the object, it passes the object reference to the method, and returns it when you use `return`

The only time where it copies the value is when you use primary types, like `int`, `char` or `double`

Answer (score 1):

It just return the current object itself.

Comment: It returns a reference to the object. Not the object itself. Subtle difference, with huge impact.

Answer (score 1):

What you say is more like the `C++` of doing such things. When you return an object(non-basic type), you will return a reference and you will not create a new object or perform a copy.

Answer (score 1):

In java atomic types (char,int,long etc.) are returned by value. Objects are always returned by reference (without cloning).

Answer (score 1):

> Does the `return obj;` creates a new object copy or return the current object itself?

--> `obj` is an object reference which points to the actual object on the heap. New object reference(by you) will be created in your method where you are assigning returned `obj`.

```
Object method() {
  //....
  return obj;
}

void methodA() {
  Object objA = method(); // obj and objA are different because of their scopes but values are same(assigned to objA). That's why both points to the same Object on heap
}
```